# SpringBoot Method 'POST' is not supported

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I upgraded from 2.7.2 Springboot version to 3.2.1.
I refactored the spring security section,it was:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS)
                .and()
                .headers().cacheControl();
    }


    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean(){
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registrationBean.setFilter(jwtAuthenticationFilter());
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns(getTokenBasedAuthEntryPoint());
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
    }

}
```

and now it is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration {


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .sessionManagement(sessionManagement ->
                        sessionManagement
                                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                )
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .headers(headers -> headers
                        .cacheControl(HeadersConfigurer.CacheControlConfig::disable)
                );

        return http.build();
    }


    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<JwtAuthenticationFilter> filterRegistrationBean(){
        FilterRegistrationBean<JwtAuthenticationFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
        registrationBean.setFilter(jwtAuthenticationFilter());
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns(getTokenBasedAuthEntryPoint());
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
    }

}
```

The problem is with my Post method from my controller that it looks like this

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("init")
@CrossOrigin
public class InitRestController {

  public static final String UNAUTHORIZED = "unauthorized {}";
  @Autowired
  AuthorizationServiceImpl authorizationService;

  @Autowired
  RestControllerUtils restControllerUtils;

  @Autowired
  CancelInitService cancelInitService;

  @Autowired
  AQListener listener;

  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InitRestController.class);

@PostMapping("messageSimulator")
  public void messageSimulator(@RequestHeader(value = "authorization") final String jwt,
                              @RequestBody CompoundMessageDTO message) throws Exception {
    try {
      authorizationService.claimJwt(jwt);
      message.setFullMessageBody(JSONUtils.toJSon(message));
      listener.processMessage(message);
    }
    catch (JwtException | IllegalArgumentException e){
      log.error(UNAUTHORIZED,e.getMessage());
      throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED,e.getMessage());
    }
  }
```

In Postman if I send a POST request I will have this in Intellij console:  Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler  and then an error: status 405 with Method POST not allowed.Is trying to serve me static resources instead of calling the method from the controller

I have a WebMvcConfig that looks like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
                .resourceChain(true)
                .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver() {
                    @Override
                    protected Resource getResource(String resourcePath, Resource location) throws IOException {
                        Resource requestedResource = location.createRelative(resourcePath);

                        return requestedResource.exists() && requestedResource.isReadable() ? requestedResource
                                : new ClassPathResource("/static/index.html");
                    }
                });
        registry.setOrder(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE);
    }
```

Why is this behaviour? It worked like this before upgrading to version 3.2.1 but now suddenly this doesn't work. I have multiple methods in that controller and for example GET method it works. Also I debugged a little bit the DispatcherServlet from libraries and I saw that the handler it's HandlerExecutionChain with ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath/static] and with 6 interceptors. I don't understand what can I do here to solve the problem, I tried multiple solutions.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this part of the code matches all URIs, even the POST method.

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
            .resourceChain(true)
```

Did you try changing the regex pattern ?

Comment: I tried to put there "static/**" but same error(No static resource init/messageSimulator), is trying to access static resources when calling the URL from my POST method .